# How can I get a webODM processing node online?

Tags: docker

I am trying to run webODM and import a dataset in a newly created project. However, it seems like it's impossible to reach the processing node. In the interface it is offline but the docker container is running.

I am running a docker container with [WebODM](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/WebODM) and can access the application through the webinterface (localhost:8000). However when I try importing images I always get an error:

```
There are no usable processing nodes.Make sure that at least one processing node is reachable and that you have granted the current user sufficient permissions to view the processing node (by going to Administration -- Processing Nodes -- Select Node -- Object Permissions -- Add User/Group and check CAN VIEW PROCESSING NODE). If you are bringing a node back online, it will take about 30 seconds for WebODM to recognize it.
```

- I checked this but the default user group already contained the role
  to view processing node.
  I tried adding my user to an additional test group containing all
  possible permissions, but it didn't work.
- also stopped the docker container, updated it (but it was
  up-to-date as I just installed it) and restarted.
- rebuild the image.
- delete the processing node and restarted the container. The node was rebuild but the problem remained.
- And checked if the node was online:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irRxO.png)

[Offline Node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8mvq.png)

How can I get the node to work?

Thank you

Comment: You're accessing http://webodm_node-odm_1:3000, but your node address is actually http://localhost:30000... You should consider using docker-compose -- it'll allow you to access nodes by hostname rather than on localhost.